# Solr: update request processor not lower casing

Tags: solr

I have the following update-request-processor to lower case all values for the given field:

```
<processor class="solr.RegexReplaceProcessorFactory">
  <str name="fieldName">my_upper_cased_field</str>
  <str name="pattern">.*</str>
  <str name="replacement">_</str>
  <bool name="literalReplacement">false</bool>
</processor>
```

However, even with `literalReplacement` as `false`, the result in the field is `_`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why would it lowercase the text - you're asking it to replace any character with `_`? Do you really need to perform this in an update request processor and not in a regular lowercase filter?

Comment: @MatsLindh I'm lower-casing a field that I do analysis on via `docValues` enabled and so that is not compatible with the lowercase filter, I must do it here. I got this lower-casing replacement string via this [link](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/schemaless-mode.html#enable-field-class-guessing). How should I lower-case here instead? Thank you.

Comment: Please add the example of how lowercase filter isn't compatible with docValues - what's the exact analysis chain and what's the input/output that shows the issue with using the proper filter; docValues should still work with the end tokens. What you're referring to is the field name mutator - lowercasing is a built-in feature for that one - the replacement shown is to remove whitespace, `-` and `.` in a field name and replace them with `_`. If you _really_ need to lowercase in a update processor, you might have to use a script processor.

Comment: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/8_5_0//solr-core/org/apache/solr/update/processor/StatelessScriptUpdateProcessorFactory.html

Comment: @MatsLindh thanks for your response. The incompatibility I referred to is related to [this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-8362).

Comment: That's a good point! Thank you for clearing that up. I think a script update processor is the way to go then, as it allows you to attach invoke Javascript as part of the update process. Calling `.toLowerCase()` on the field content should give you the result you're looking for.